# split only emoji in a list, but keep text

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I have a list that looks like this:

```
['', 'today', 'happy', '']
```

and I want to split only the emoji icons, not text :

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'today', 'happy', '', '', '']
```

I try these code but it didn't return what I want:

```
!pip install emoji
import emoji
emoji_list = list(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)

def split_emoji(input):
    result = []
    str_i = str(input)
    for i in str_i:
      if i in [*emoji_list]:
        result.append(i)
      else:
        result.append(i)

    return result
```

and the result:

```
[['', '', '', '', '', ''],
 ['t', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'y'],
 ['h', 'a', 'p', 'p', 'y'],
 ['', '', '']]
```

The icons are split perfectly, but I want to keep the text.

What should I do?

Comment: In your code, you always append `i` to `result`, whether or not it is in the `emoji_list`?

Comment: That character is not in the emoji list. Try this test: print("" in emoji_list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert strings with emojis in lists and put the words in a list according to the result of [str.isalnum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

```
>>> l = ['', 'today', 'happy', ''] 
>>> res = list(itertools.chain(*[list(el) if not el.isalnum() else [el] for el in l]))
>>> res
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'today', 'happy', '', '', '']
```

or also

```
>>> res = []
>>> for el in l:
...     if el.isalnum():
...             res.append(el)
...     else:
...             res+=list(el)
... 
>>> res
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'today', 'happy', '', '', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using extra for-loop to iterate list element of characters and validate char has emoji if yes then set is_emoji flag true and append emoji into list.

**Ex.**

```
import emoji
emoji_list = list(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI)


myList = ['', 'today', 'happy', ''] 


def split_emoji(textArray):
    result = []
    for word in textArray:
        is_emoji = False

        # iterate element of characters and check char is emoji if yes 
        # then append into result list and set is_emogi flag true.
        for char in word:
            if char in [*emoji_list]:
                result.append(char)
                is_emoji = True

        # check is_emoji flag is false then append string into list.  
        if not is_emoji:
            result.append(word)

    return result

print(split_emoji(myList))
```

**O/P:**

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', 'today', 'happy', '', '', '']
```